# Removing specific patterns from rows

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to remove some part from a text, specifically information between the first - (if there is any) at the beginning of the sentence.

For example:

```
My_col
23 Mar 2020 - this is the first example
this is the - second example
21 March 2020 - this is another example - 
...
```

Expected output should be:

```
New_Col
this is the first example
this is the - second example
this is another example - 
...
```

I tried with `df['New_Col']=df['My_col'].str.split('—', expand=True,n=0)[0]` but it splits the sentence because of str.split.

Comment: Do you just want to remove a date at the start of string? `df['My_col'].str.replace(r'^\d{1,2}\s+\w+\s+\d{4}\s+-\s+', '')`?

Comment: unfortunately it does not work. There might be also something like this: `23 Mar, 2020 - other sentences` and I would need to remove `23 Mar, 2020 -`

Comment: So what is the rule? Try `.replace(r'^\d{1,2}\s+\w+,?\s+\d{4}\s+-\s+', '')`

Comment: It would be something like this: number `(1 or 2 digits) word (punctuation) number -` If there is this pattern, it should be at the start of the senntence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['New_Col'] = df['My_col'].str.replace(r'^\d{1,2}\s+\w+\W+\d{4}\s+[-——]\s+', '')
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespace chars
- `\w+` - a word
- `\W+` - one or more non-word chars
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `\s+[-——]\s+` - a `-`, `—` or `—` enclosed with one or more whitespaces.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/MEGAJ6/2).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['My_col']=df['My_col'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('—', '-') if type(x)==str else x)
df['New_Col']=df['My_col'].apply(lambda x: x[x.find('-')+1:] if type(x)==str else x)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have got this error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Strange. Are there any floats inside your My_col column?

Comment: I updated the answer, so that it will run only for strings and ignore other types of data. Please check again

Comment: What exactly is —? It's 2 - next to each other? In any case, you can add some additional elif in the lambda function so that it will check if — is x so that it will search for it. Let me know if you need any help. Even better, you can run a replace('—', '-') before

Comment: I added a line that replaces any — by - before the main function, please check again

Comment: Thank you so much IoaTzimas

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, one is string replacement using `re.sub()`:

```
import pandas as pd 
import re
  
# Let's create a Dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame({'My_col':['23 Mar 2020 - this is the first example',
'this is the - second example',
'21 March 2020 - this is another example - ',
'...'] }) 

df['New_Col']=df['My_col'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('^[^-—]+ [-—] ', '', x) )
```

Comment: Hi wp78de, thanks for updating the answer. I tried as follows:     df['My_col']=df['My_col'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('^[^-—]+ [-—] ', '', x) if type(x)==str else x ) as I have got similar error as in IoaTzimas comments. Unfortunately it does not replace the - (or -—). There are still the values

Comment: @Val Can you provide a sample string that does not get updated? Are those multi-line strings or individual strings?

Comment: an example could be '29 feb 2020 — TEL AVIV' or '17 2020 —' . I think it is the same symbol